# Query executed from IPostInsertEventListener.OnPostInsert triggers OnPostInsert again

Tags: nhibernate, event-listener

I've an IPostInsertEventListener which executes an NHibernate query which in turn for some reason causes a new call to the same IPostInsertEventListener which eventually leads to a StackOverflowException.

Is it just bad practice executing NHibernate queries from an IPostInsertEventListener (I have an option of pre-loading and caching the data when the listener is created)?

Why would a query trigger a post insert event?

Comment: No, I'm not creating a new session.

Comment: I know this is old, but did you ever figure this one out?

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a bug if you ask me in nhibernate.  What we have done to "fix" this since we are using the `thread_static` session context is to execute the logic in the implementations of things like `IPostInsertEventListener` in a separate thread such that it will utilize a different `ISession` to avoid the issue.